# SQL DATABASE(postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

```
ERROR:  could not open file "C:\Users\lenovo\Downloads\Owners.csv" for reading: Permission denied
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
SQL state: 42501
```

I am trying to  import a csv file into postgresql.  But this error pops up. I search everywhere. But i Couldn't get the answer of it PLEASE HELP ME.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!

Comment: I trying to solve this. So many times .But i couldn't understand about it. I am new to Postgresql

Comment: Please, add [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

`COPY mytable FROM /path/thefile.csv WITH CSV,HEADER;` is executed **by the DBMS server**, the .csv-file is read by the server. The server (typically) runs as user *postgres*, which cannot access arbitrary users's files. (Also: the client and server don't have to be running on the *same machine*) There are two possible solutions to this:

- copy the csv-file to a place where the server can access it, in `/tmp/`, or somewhere under its home-directory.
- use psql's `\copy mytable(col1,col2,...) FROM '/path/file.csv'...` (slightly different syntax)